# Creating a new variable in a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame in R. For example, the data frame is called X and includes the following columns:

```
x1 = c(1,0,0,0)
X2 = c(0,0,0,0)
X3 = c(0,0,0,0)
X4 = c(0,0,1,0)
```

I want to add a condition, that for each of the 4 subjects, if at least one column is 1, then a new variable will be created getting 1. Else, if all are 0's the new variable will be 0.

I tried this:

```
if (X$X1 == 1 || X$X2 == 1 || X$X3 == 1 || X$X4 == 1 || X$X5 == 1) 
{
  NewVar = 1
}
else { NewVar = 0 }
```

However I keep getting an error:

> Error: unexpected 'else' in "else" and in my code R studio say:
>   Unexpected token 'else'

Can you please assist me with finding the problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Use `X$NewVar <- as.integer(rowSums(X)>0)`

Comment: `df$newvar <- as.integer(rowSums(df) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums`

```
X$NewVar <- as.integer(rowSums(X) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, but what was wrong with my if-else code? What happens if I'll have more variables in the data frame and I will wish to condition on only some of them? For example, if I want to condition on X1,X2 only ?

Comment: @user2899944  You were using `if/else` (works for a single element) and it is not vectorized.  If you want a vectorized option it is `ifelse`.  Second, `||` should be `|`

Comment: I see. One more question please. If I take your first idea above, but my data frame includes one more variable (subjectID), how can I sum the row excluding the first column?

Comment: @user2899944 In that case `as.integer(rowSums(X[-1])>0)`